Prisma prismaSchemaFolder Preview Feature Not Working as Expected
I am trying to use multiple Prisma files with Prisma, and I have reviewed everything, including Prisma's own documentation. However, whenever I run npx prisma generate, I get the following error:
> npx prisma generate
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from src/prisma/schema/schema.prisma
Error: 
You don't have any models defined in your schema.prisma, so nothing will be generated.
You can define a model like this:

model User {
  id    String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email String  @unique
  name  String?
}

More information in our documentation:
https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

File & Folder Structure:

schema.prisma:
datasource db_main {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("MONGODB_URI")
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["prismaSchemaFolder"]
}

contact.prisma
datasource db_contact {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("MONGODB_URI")
}

model ContactRequest {
  id          String  @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  email       String
  message String?

  @@map("contact_requests")
}

Why am I getting this error? I have checked the things in the documentation and other sources, but I am still experiencing this issue. I would appreciate it if you could help, thank you.

Check to see if in your package.json file "prisma.schema" is pointing at the directory and not the "prisma.schema" file:
from:
"prisma": {
    "schema": "./prisma/schema/schema.prisma"
},

to:
"prisma": {
    "schema": "./prisma/schema"
},

